# Linq - Intersecting 2 Lists by properties in child objects

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to merge two lists..  I often do this successfully when I have merging something like `ProductsList1.Product.Id` with `ProductList2.Product.Id`  , however In this case its more Like `ProductsList.Product.Id` with `ProductCategoriesList.ProductCategory.ProductId`. The 3rd level property is what's getting me!

```
    // LIST OF PRODUCTS IN RESULT SETS
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    products.Add(new Product() { Id = 1 });
    products.Add(new Product() { Id = 2 });

    // LIST OF ALL PRODUCTS AND THEIR CATEGORY TAXONOMIES
    List<ProductCategory> allProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>();
    allProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { ProductId = 1, CategoryUid = 101, ParentCategoryUid = 30 });
    allProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { ProductId = 1, CategoryUid = 30, ParentCategoryUid = 2 });
    allProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { ProductId = 1, CategoryUid = 2, ParentCategoryUid = 1 });
    allProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { ProductId = 3, CategoryUid = 101, ParentCategoryUid = 43 });
    allProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { ProductId = 3, CategoryUid = 43, ParentCategoryUid = 8 });
    allProductCategories.Add(new ProductCategory() { ProductId = 3, CategoryUid = 8, ParentCategoryUid = 1 });

    // NEED TO MERGE THE 2ND LIST INTO THE 1ST BY PRODUCTID VIA SQL EQUIV INNER JOIN
    // END RESULT SHOULD BE products list has 2 objects. one object has 1 list product category with 3 child objects
    // THIS IS THE CLOSEST I GOT
    products.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(allProductCategories.Select(a => a.ProductId).ToList());
}

public class Product
{
    private int _id;
    private List<ProductCategory> _productCategories;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories; }
        set { _productCategories = value; }
    }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    private int _productId;
    private int _categoryUid;
    private int _parentCategoryUid;

    public int ProductId
    {
        get { return _productId; }
        set { _productId = value; }
    }

    public int CategoryUid
    {
        get { return _categoryUid; }
        set { _categoryUid = value; }
    }

    public int ParentCategoryUid
    {
        get { return _parentCategoryUid; }
        set { _parentCategoryUid = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first and second list are not of the same type so how do you plan on merging them?  What is the end result that you are trying to achieve, i.e. a list of what type?

Comment: Okay, I see that you continued your question as a comment in your code block.  Probably best if you don't do that in the future.  That being said, it is still not clear to me from your comment what the end result should be.

Answer (score 2):

Following query will do the job:

```
var result  =   products.Join(allProductCategories, p => p.Id, 
                              pc => pc.ProductId, (p, pc) => new { p, pc})
                            .GroupBy(x => x.p.Id)
                            .Select(x => new Product{ Id = x.Key, ProductCategories = x.Select(y => y.pc).ToList()});
```

> Requirement:

- Get Data from two different lists, which have common Id, and create a merged version, which contain Id of the parent `Product`, and all the matching rows of the `ProductCategory`

**Explanation:**

- Inner Join two list on Id
- Groupby `ProductId` to aggregate the `ProductCategory` data
- Select them in separate collection, where Id is the Key and data is the collection of all the aggregated / grouped results

You may run it using Linqpad and `result.Dump()`, will provide a clear view of the final result

Comment: I'm slightly following this solution, but I'm having difficulty getting results to be of type  List<Product>

Comment: Check now, I have edited the response to produce the `IEnumerable<Product>` as a response, earlier I was creating an `IEnumerble<AnonymousType>`, it is a very small change

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// LIST OF PRODUCTS IN RESULT SETS
List<Product> products = new List<Product> {
    new Product() {Id = 1, ProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()}, 
    new Product() {Id = 2, ProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()}
};

// LIST OF ALL PRODUCTS AND THEIR CATEGORY TAXONOMIES
List<ProductCategory> allProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>
{
    new ProductCategory() {ProductId = 1, CategoryUid = 101, ParentCategoryUid = 30},
    new ProductCategory() {ProductId = 1, CategoryUid = 30, ParentCategoryUid = 2},
    new ProductCategory() {ProductId = 1, CategoryUid = 2, ParentCategoryUid = 1},
    new ProductCategory() {ProductId = 3, CategoryUid = 101, ParentCategoryUid = 43},
    new ProductCategory() {ProductId = 3, CategoryUid = 43, ParentCategoryUid = 8},
    new ProductCategory() {ProductId = 3, CategoryUid = 8, ParentCategoryUid = 1}
};

// General logic going on here:
// Add all ProductCategory where the ProductID is equal
// to the Prdoduct.ID to the current Product.ProductCategories
products.ForEach(pr=>
    allProductCategories.Where(pC=>
        pC.ProductId.Equals(pr.Id)).ToList().ForEach(pC=>
            pr.ProductCategories.Add(pC)));

// products.ToList().ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.ProductCategories.Count));
```

---

Output:

> 3
>
> 0

---

<strike>I do not know if there is an easier way using the intersect method, but this one does work!</strike>

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) (for using `Enumerable.Intersect`) you would need to implement a custom [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) using multiple types. Because of that it is currently impossible to do such things or would simple take more lines of code than my current solution.

If you do want to know more about [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/intersect), I suggest visiting [*dotnetperls.com*](https://www.dotnetperls.com/)!